# Haskell Tree with edge information

Tags: haskell, tree

Does this sort of data structure exist in a Haskell library? I did some searching, but couldn't find anything helpful. I'd like to use an existing type instead of defining my own - it seems like something that should be out there.

```
data MyTree e n = Node { rootLabel :: n
                       , subForest :: Map e (MyTree e n)
                       }
```

The idea is that it's very similar to Data.Tree, but edges can hold information as well as nodes.

If you have a path through the tree (of type [e]) you can find the rootLabel (of type n) in O(log(n)). As far as I can tell, you can't do this with Data.Tree because you have to scan each of a node's children to find if it's the node that the path progresses to. This is because the type of Data.Tree's subForest is [Tree a].

In particular, I'm interested in an implementation that exposes a function with a type similar to:

```
getNextLevel :: e -> MyTree e n -> MyTree e n
```

that will dive one level deeper in the tree, given an edge to traverse.

Answer (score 4):

This data type looks a lot like a trie, for which there are many packages available on Hackage.

Comment: Data.Trie assumes the type of e is ByteString; I'm hoping for something a little more general =\

Comment: @Litherum By my count, there are twelve different packages providing tries, and only one of them is specialized to `ByteString`. Perhaps you should keep looking.

Answer (score -1):

You can always use a graph library and just ensure yourself that you keep it as a tree.